# Issue while saving a Transparent Canvas in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have created a Grid in WPF with Red background. The Grid contains a transparent Canvas with some fixed size. Now while trying to export the Canvas as Image, I am getting an image with black background. But when there is some color in Canvas (say White or Red), I am getting a proper image. Can anybody please tell me why the image is generating with black background if a Canvas has a transparent color.

Example:

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
            grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            grid.Width = 500;
            grid.Height = 300;

            Canvas c = new Canvas();
            c.Width = 500;
            c.Height = 300;
            c.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
            c.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(c_MouseLeftButtonUp);

            grid.Children.Add(c);

            LayoutRoot.Children.Add(grid);
```

Inside MouseEvent handler of Canvas, I am saving it as jpg image.

Comment: can you post the code that you are using to save the image  in the xaml.cs file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Inside MouseEvent handler of Canvas, I am saving it as **jpg** image.

Save it as `PNG`. These type of images are specialized in saving transparent backgrounds.

Comment: But why it is not possible with jpg?

Comment: Thats how **jpg** is intended to be as a format.... (without transparency) .... see this http://www.talkgraphics.com/showthread.php?22385-How-do-I-make-jpeg-image-background-transparent